Is it possible to install docker CE on windows server 2019?
Is it possible to install docker CE on windows server 2019?
Hi everyone, I'm trying to install docker on windows server 2019 to run some containers required at my work. I followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce#windows-server-1 using the Docker CE / Mobby option
Once docker was installed, I tried to download and run a test container with the following command: docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
However, I get the following error:

error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon
is not running: Post
"http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.47/images/create?fromImage=mcr.microsoft.com%2Fwindows%2Fnanoserver&tag=ltsc2022":
open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file
specified.

I tried restarting docker with restart-service *docker*. But I get the following error:

restart-service : Failed to start service 'Docker Engine (docker)'.

I don't know what else to do or how to fix the problem, I tried uninstalling docker but I couldn't find an uninstall command
I hope someone can help me please. Thanks for reading
